# What is wrong with this deduction to show that within a multiplet different state has different square angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am watching Susskinds's lecture [Advanced Quantum Mechanics Lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKYs_xwWKY4), in which he introduced square angular momentum operator $L^2$, which can be written as
$$
L^2=L_z^2+L_-L_++L_z
$$
where
$$
L_\pm=L_x\pm iL_y
$$

Besides, he argued that the spectrum of $L$ can only be $m,m-1,\cdots,-m+1,-m$ in which $m$ is an integer or half-integer. If we denote $|m\rangle$ the eigenvector corresponds to eigenvalue $m$, we have
$$
L_\pm|l\rangle=|l\pm 1\rangle\;\text{or}\;0
$$

In the lecture he showed that $L^2|m\rangle=m(m+1)|m\rangle$ for $m$ the highest eigenvalue, by
$$
\begin{align*}
L^2|m\rangle&=L_z^2|m\rangle+L_-L_+|m\rangle+L_z|m\rangle\\
&=m^2|m\rangle+0+m|m\rangle\\
&=m(m+1)|m\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

Then he left an exercise to show that for any $-m\leqslant l< m$, we also have $|l\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $L^2$ with eigenvalue $m(m+1)$.

In the lecture, he hinted by showing that it suffices to show that $L^2$ commutes with $L_i$ for $i=x,y,z$, which gives us
$$
L^2|m-1\rangle=L^2L_-|m\rangle=L_-L^2|m\rangle=L_-m(m+1)|m\rangle=m(m+1)L_-|m\rangle=m(m-1)|m-1\rangle
$$

I believe it is true since I find the [proof](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node214.html)  online.

However, my question is that, **why the following proof is wrong**.

I tried to mimic the proof for $|m\rangle$ to have that

$$
\begin{align*}
L^2|k\rangle&=L_z^2|k\rangle+L_-L_+|k\rangle+L_z|k\rangle\\
&=k^2|k\rangle+L_-L_+|k+1\rangle+k|k\rangle\\
&=k^2|k\rangle+|k\rangle+k|k\rangle\\
&=(k^2+k+1)|k\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

which shows that $|k\rangle$ does not have eigenvalue $m(m+1)$ but $k^2+k+1$ for $k<m$.

Comment: Since the video is 2 hours long, could you pls provide a time stamp so we can figure out where this anomalous $L_z$ came from?

Comment: never mind, it's a 20:00-- and of course Suskind is right, since $Lx$ and $L_y$ don't commute.

Comment: Something is wrong here. How can you add $L_z^2$ to $L_z$?

Comment: @AaronStevens It's just because $\hbar = 1$ here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that that you assumed
$$L_\pm |k \rangle = |k \pm 1 \rangle.$$
In fact, there are also normalization factors, 
$$L_+ |k \rangle = \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1) - k(k+1)} |k + 1 \rangle, \quad L_- |k+1 \rangle = \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1) - k(k+1)} |k \rangle.$$
When you raise and subsequently lower, you get
$$L_- L_+ |k \rangle = (\ell(\ell+1) - k(k+1)) |k \rangle.$$
Hence we have
$$(L_z^2 + L_- L_+ + L_z) |k \rangle = (k^2 + \ell(\ell+1) - k(k+1) + k) |k \rangle = \ell(\ell+1) |k \rangle$$
just as expected.