# Is there any missing constraint to deduce that angular momentum is quantized in pure math?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Susskind's [Advanced Quantum Mechanics Lecture 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O1NhGP07Xo), he shows the quantization of eigenvalues of $L_z$ using the fact that if $m$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $\psi$, then $L_\pm\psi$ is also an eigenvector (up to a normalization factor) with eigenvalue $m\pm 1$, until being killed. Thus, the eigenvalues of $L_z$ must be
$$
l,l-1,\cdots,-l+1,-l
$$
where $l$ is a (half-)integer.

In the lecture I believe he used following two assumption:

- The number of eigenvalues is finite, since those states are what physicists care.
- The system is rotational symmetrical.

However, I **failed to deduce the spectrum of $L_z$ in pure mathematics based on those assumptions**.

The first assumption indicates the spectrum has a maximum $l$ and minimum $m$, which can be any real number.

The second assumption indicates that $m=-l$ and the spectrum is reflective symmetrical.

Up to now, we can conclude *mathematically* that the spectrum *contains* $\{l,l-1,\cdots,-l+1,-l\}$ *as a subset*. But we still do not eliminate following cases:

$$
\{1, 0.7, 0.3, -0.3, -0.7, -1\}
$$

I guess $L_+$ killing both $\psi_{0.7}$ and $\psi_1$ may violate some hidden assumption. Could anyone help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity $\left[L_{z},L_{\pm}\right]=\pm\hbar L_{\pm}$?

Comment: @eranreches yes, but does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/449719/what-is-wrong-with-this-deduction-to-show-that-within-a-multiplet-different-stat) about this subject, you've neglected the normalization factor.

The reason that $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ form a set of valid values is because, if you keep trying to raise beyond $1$ or lower beyond $-1$, the normalization factor will be zero. That is, there is no state beyond $\pm 1$.

If you had $0.3$, it's easy to check this will never happen: either you will be able to raise upward forever, or lower downward forever, or both. (Try it yourself, by plugging in various values for $\ell$.) This is covered in detail in any book on quantum mechanics, such as Griffiths.

In general, I wouldn't recommend using Susskind's lectures as a serious introduction. They're okay for getting the gist, but there's not enough detail given to actually check the mathematical steps properly. If you want to learn the subject, try a book or normal lecture course.

Comment: Got it, thanks! and I planned to try a book after finishing his introductory lectures. BTW, any recommendations?

Comment: @HanXu Griffiths is the most common, Shankar is at a similar level but more mathematically careful.