# Total angular momentum operator on $|m\rangle$ and $|m-1\rangle$ results in different eigenvalue

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space

In the lectures by Prof. Leonard Susskind, he mentioned that the total angular momentum squared operator can be represented by 
$$
L^2 = L_z^2 + L_z + L_- L_+
$$ 
($L_+, L_-$ being ladder operators). He then used it to show the $L^2$ of $|m\rangle$ is $m(m+1)$  ($m$ stands for magnetic quantum number). Finally, he proposed that if $L_-$ commutes with $L^2$ (which is true) then all $(2L+1)$ states will have same $L^2$. However if I apply $L^2 = L_z^2 + L_z + L_- L_+$ to $|m-1\rangle$ directly, it will give me $m^2-m+1 != m(m+1)$

I would like to know where is the flaw in my calculation.

[He mentioned it around 26:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKYs_xwWKY4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this deduction to show that within a multiplet different state has different square angular momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449719/) Literally the exact same question inspired by watching the exact same lecture.

Comment: The problem is that you can't get the right answer just going by what Susskind tells you, because he has dropped normalization factors. In general, casual resources like Susskind's lectures should just be used to get the intuition. You shouldn't expect to be able to actually verify equations after watching them, because he leaves too much out.

Comment: Thank you very much!